# How to animate data visualization in Processing?

Tags: processing, data-visualization

I'm trying to create an animated data visualization and currently only know how to do the following "static" code, which puts a string of dots in a straight line. How do I make them jump up and down? Also, if there is anyone in Dublin, Ireland, who wouldn't mind giving a few tutorial sessions to a couple of college students working on a data visualization project in Processing, we have a small budget to compensate you for your time. Thanks very much!

For now, here's the code I was talking about...

```java
SimpleSpreadsheetManager sm;
String sUrl = "t6mq_WLV5c5uj6mUNSryBIA";
String googleUser = "USERNAME";
String googlePass = "PASSWORD";

void setup() {
  //This code happens once, right when our sketch is launched
 size(800,800);
 background(0);
 smooth();

 //Ask for the list of numbers
 int[] numbers = getNumbers();
fill(255,40);
noStroke();
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  ellipse(numbers[i] * 8, width/2, 8,8);
};

};
void draw() {
  //This code happens once every frame.
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially the x position you use for drawing the ellipse is a number value you get from external data. You need a variable that changes value. Redrawing the ellipse at the updated value should get things animated.

Take this basic example:

```
float x,y;//position variables for the ellipse

void setup(){
  size(800,800);
  smooth();
  fill(255,40);
  noStroke();
  y = 400;
}
void draw(){
  //update values
  x = mouseX + (sin(frameCount * .05) * 30);//update x to an arbitrary value
  //draw
  background(0);//clear the screen for the new frame
  ellipse(x,y,8,8);//draw the ellipse at the new position
}
```

the x variable is a bit like numbers[i] - just a value that chances. 
Nothing special happens in draw() other than clearing the screen(by calling `background()`) and drawing. The example above uses an arbitrary value, but with your setup that might be something else, maybe a certain value in a data set that changes in time (like the population of a country, etc.)

Another handy thing to keep in mind is the separation between the data and visuals code wise. If values in the data set are higher than what can be displayed on screen as raw values, you can [map()](http://processing.org/reference/map_.html) values so they can be viewer, add some sort of navigation controls, etc. The values analysed will not be affected by what's being displayed. In programming terms this separation between the data/model, the visuals/view (how the data is rendered) and the controls/controller is known as the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.
This might be a bit much for people just starting with code, but just being aware of the separation without worrying to much on the specific implementation can be helpful.

Here's a very basic example having the width of the sketch mapped to the size of the data (numbers)

```
SimpleSpreadsheetManager sm;
String sUrl = "t6mq_WLV5c5uj6mUNSryBIA";
String googleUser = "USERNAME";
String googlePass = "PASSWORD";

int[] numbers;//data used for visualisation

void setup() {
  //sketch setup
 size(800,800);
 smooth();
 fill(255,40);
 noStroke();
 //retrieve data
 numbers = getNumbers();
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  int numId = int(map(mouseX,0,width,0,numbers.length));//map mouse x position based on sketch width and data size 
  ellipse(numbers[numId] * 8, height/2, 8,8);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, George and Hamed!

Answer (score 0):

For an animation you need one or more parameters that their values changed in time, currently there is a library for processing which do such things: [Ani](http://www.looksgood.de/libraries/Ani/)
For more information see the site and provided examples.